# How to secure sensitive data in WCF client app?

Tags: .net, wcf, security

I have WCF web service and client that calls this service, This client will be deployed in many locations. I have to authenticate and authorize each client uniquely. So each location will have their unique user name and password.

Now my questions are

1. how to identify each client uniquely?
2. how to store some sensitive data in client side?

I thought about few approaches,

1. Using a cert to identify the client. I have to generate and deploy certificate.
2. Having an active directory on server side, and let each client use a windows user account.
3. Encrypting user name and password and store them in config file. I believe encrypting config files using aspnet_regiis wont help me, since anyone can decrypt it, if they gain access to the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be devided into three parts. Two are directly related to security in WCF and one is out of scope.

**Authentication and authorization** - yes this is possible. WCF offers several settings to allow authenticating client and provide its roles. You can also build your own. The most common scenario for authenticating clients which are not in your AD domain is using user name and password credentials with custom validation on service or using client certificates.

**Confidentality and integrity** - because of your consern about security you should also involve secure transport of credentials (and message data). If you do not provide secure transport anybody on the network will be able to sniff communication and steal credentials (or data). Attacker will also be able to intercept communication and modify transported data. To secure communication you need transport security (TLS,SSL / HTTPS) or message security - in Internet scenario provided by certificates.

**Securing credentials on client** - this is mostly out of your control. Once you deploy client application with credentials to client machine which is not under your control you can never enforce security of provided credentials. It is up to your users / customers. If you somehow include credentials in your application skilled end user / attacker will probably always be able to get them. But this is problem of every secure solution - somebody must have access to credentials.

Comment: Confidentality and integrity - Agree, I have SSL to protect messages from sniffing. Securing credentials on client - is my concern. I understand once the machine is compromised, there is much I can do. But what is the best I can do in this situvation, place a cert, so this cert is username & password, or encrypt user name & password and place it in config file or use windows user account?

Comment: @iraSenthil: I would not provide windows user account. Certificate has to be installed on the client machine. It can also be configured to not allow export private key so it should not be transferable to other machine. Also in some configuration you should be able to map certificate to windows account (I have never tryed it). User name and password is much easier but in such case the security is up to you - you can encrypt configuration section but still your client application must have key to decrypt it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to favor certs. They're more difficult to compromise than u/p's.

If your client data is fairly lightweight, just [encipher an XML file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746.aspx) using symmetric encryption in the client app.

If you're concerned about the client app being compromised, you can encipher the data asymmetrically using the server's public key. Then, when you need it, you send the lightweight enciphered data to the server and get it back deciphered in a WCF response. That might be workable if it only happens on session startup (otherwise, that's a lot of traffic).

Comment: I have a cert to encrypt the traffic, so I am not concerned about sniffing. I am concerned about giving some identity to a client and securing that identity.

Comment: Certs are definitely the way to go, then, IMHO. BTW, I'm not concerned about the security of the traffic, just the volume. If the user had to call back to the server to get their data deciphered for every operation, that would be onerous and probably latent.